# Abort trap: 6 in Mongodb - MAC OS

Tags: mongodb, macos

I am trying to run my mongodb. So I go to the appropriate folder's location and type:

```
$ mongod --dbpath=data
```

Then I get a funny message which I don't know how to fix.

```
----- BEGIN BACKTRACE -----
...
...
...
----- END BACKTRACE -----
Abort trap: 6
```

Any ideas how can this be fixed?

Thanks,
Theo.

Comment: well it's `--dbpath <directory>` with no `=` in it, but surely there's more information than that.

Comment: @ Neil Lunn . Could you be more specific please?

Comment: Funny because "specific" is what we are asking of you. The stacktrace you have omitted is where the "only" useful information is. The abort trap means nothing.

Comment: How did you install MongoDB? What are your specific versions of MongoDB server (`mongod --version`) and macOS (`sw_vers`)? Can you edit your post with the details of the log lines before the backtrace and include the actual contents of the backtrace? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your data folder is corrupted.
Delete that folder and open up the terminal on the parent folder of data folder and type:
mongod --dbpath=data

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.