# Mongodb keeps on terminating with abort trap 6

Tags: mongodb

This issue only came up yesterday. And I tried restarting my machine many times, but it is still there.

```
Users-MacBook-Pro-3:~ user$ mongod --dbpath /Volumes/A2P7/mongodb --logpath /Volumes/A2P7/mongodb-log/mongo.log

{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-13T03:12:26.912Z"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20697,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Renamed existing log file","attr":{"oldLogPath":"/Volumes/A2P7/mongodb-log/mongo.log","newLogPath":"/Volumes/A2P7/mongodb-log/mongo.log.2021-01-13T03-12-26"}}
Abort trap: 6
```

This is my latest log:

```
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-13T11:12:26.919+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-13T11:12:27.043+08:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-13T11:12:27.044+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648602, "ctx":"main","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen in use."}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-13T11:12:27.049+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":6029,"port":27017,"dbPath":"/Volumes/A2P7/mongodb","architecture":"64-bit","host":"Users-MacBook-Pro-3.local"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-13T11:12:27.049+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"4.4.2","gitVersion":"15e73dc5738d2278b688f8929aee605fe4279b0e","modules":[],"allocator":"system","environment":{"distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-13T11:12:27.050+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Mac OS X","version":"17.7.0"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-13T11:12:27.050+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{"storage":{"dbPath":"/Volumes/A2P7/mongodb"},"systemLog":{"destination":"file","path":"/Volumes/A2P7/mongodb-log/mongo.log"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-13T11:12:27.052+08:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22271,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Detected unclean shutdown - Lock file is not empty","attr":{"lockFile":"/Volumes/A2P7/mongodb/mongod.lock"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-13T11:12:27.067+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22270,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Storage engine to use detected by data files","attr":{"dbpath":"/Volumes/A2P7/mongodb","storageEngine":"wiredTiger"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-13T11:12:27.067+08:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22302,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Recovering data from the last clean checkpoint."}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-13T11:12:27.067+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22315,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Opening WiredTiger","attr":{"config":"create,cache_size=15872M,session_max=33000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000,close_scan_interval=10,close_handle_minimum=250),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=[recovery_progress,checkpoint_progress,compact_progress],"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-13T11:12:27.558+08:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22435,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger error","attr":{"error":-31809,"message":"[1610507547:558091][6029:0x7fffa74be380], connection: __wt_turtle_read, 387: WiredTiger.turtle: fatal turtle file read error: WT_TRY_SALVAGE: database corruption detected"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-13T11:12:27.558+08:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22435,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger error","attr":{"error":-31804,"message":"[1610507547:558142][6029:0x7fffa74be380], connection: __wt_turtle_read, 387: the process must exit and restart: WT_PANIC: WiredTiger library panic"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-13T11:12:27.558+08:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"-",        "id":23089,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Fatal assertion","attr":{"msgid":50853,"file":"src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_util.cpp","line":520}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-13T11:12:27.558+08:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"-",        "id":23090,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"\n\n***aborting after fassert() failure\n\n"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-13T11:12:27.558+08:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4757800, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Writing fatal message","attr":{"message":"Got signal: 6 (Abort trap: 6).\n"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-13T11:12:27.657+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31431,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"BACKTRACE: {bt}","attr":{"bt":{"backtrace":[{"a":"10AE5F52C","b":"108CFB000","o":"216452C","s":"_ZN5mongo18stack_trace_detail12_GLOBAL__N_119printStackTraceImplERKNS1_7OptionsEPNS_14StackTraceSinkE","s+":"10C"},{"a":"10AE60C38","b":"108CFB000","o":"2165C38","s":"_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceEv","s+":"28"},{"a":"10AE5E76B","b":"108CFB000","o":"216376B","s":"_ZN5mongo12_GLOBAL__N_116abruptQuitActionEiP9__siginfoPv","s+":"BB"},{"a":"7FFF6F142F5A","b":"7FFF6F141000","o":"1F5A","s":"_sigtramp","s+":"1A"},{"a":"0"},{"a":"7FFF6EEE01AE","b":"7FFF6EE83000","o":"5D1AE","s":"abort","s+":"7F"},{"a":"10AE45C67","b":"108CFB000","o":"214AC67","s":"_ZN5mongo25fassertFailedWithLocationEiPKcj","s+":"197"},{"a":"108DC82DB","b":"108CFB000","o":"CD2DB","s":"_ZN5mongo12_GLOBAL__N_141mdb_handle_error_with_startup_suppressionEP18__wt_event_handlerP12__wt_sessioniPKc","s+":"1FB"},{"a":"108F2D8E7","b":"108CFB000","o":"2328E7","s":"__eventv","s+":"607"},{"a":"108F2DB66","b":"108CFB000","o":"232B66","s":"__wt_panic_func","s+":"FD"},{"a":"108ED6AFA","b":"108CFB000","o":"1DBAFA","s":"__wt_turtle_read","s+":"2EA"},{"a":"108ED66DC","b":"108CFB000","o":"1DB6DC","s":"__wt_turtle_validate_version","s+":"31C"},{"a":"108E3B478","b":"108CFB000","o":"140478","s":"wiredtiger_open","s+":"2448"},{"a":"108D6F5C7","b":"108CFB000","o":"745C7","s":"_ZN5mongo18WiredTigerKVEngine15_openWiredTigerERKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEENS1_9allocatorIcEEEES9_","s+":"97"},{"a":"108D6D19E","b":"108CFB000","o":"7219E","s":"_ZN5mongo18WiredTigerKVEngineC2ERKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEENS1_9allocatorIcEEEES9_PNS_11ClockSourceES9_mmbbbb","s+":"156E"},{"a":"108D71B58","b":"108CFB000","o":"76B58","s":"_ZN5mongo18WiredTigerKVEngineC1ERKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEENS1_9allocatorIcEEEES9_PNS_11ClockSourceES9_mmbbbb","s+":"38"},{"a":"108D4B5F7","b":"108CFB000","o":"505F7","s":"_ZNK5mongo12_GLOBAL__N_117WiredTigerFactory6createERKNS_19StorageGlobalParamsEPKNS_21StorageEngineLockFileE","s+":"337"},{"a":"1097C088A","b":"108CFB000","o":"AC588A","s":"_ZN5mongo23initializeStorageEngineEPNS_14ServiceContextENS_22StorageEngineInitFlagsE","s+":"77A"},{"a":"108D071A3","b":"108CFB000","o":"C1A3","s":"_ZN5mongo12_GLOBAL__N_114_initAndListenEPNS_14ServiceContextEi","s+":"463"},{"a":"108CFD5FA","b":"108CFB000","o":"25FA","s":"_ZN5mongo12_GLOBAL__N_111mongoDbMainEiPPcS2_","s+":"15DA"},{"a":"108CFC019","b":"108CFB000","o":"1019","s":"main","s+":"9"},{"a":"7FFF6EE34015","b":"7FFF6EE33000","o":"1015","s":"start","s+":"1"}],"processInfo":{"mongodbVersion":"4.4.2","gitVersion":"15e73dc5738d2278b688f8929aee605fe4279b0e","compiledModules":[],"uname":{"sysname":"Darwin","release":"17.7.0","version":"Darwin Kernel Version 17.7.0: Fri Jul  6 19:54:51 PDT 2018; root:xnu-4570.71.3~2/RELEASE_X86_64","machine":"x86_64"},"somap":[{"path":"/usr/local/bin/mongod","machType":2,"b":"108CFB000","vmaddr":"100000000","buildId":"6638114D9C633CBCAB6B5A0B73A8739A"},{"path":"/usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib","machType":6,"b":"7FFF6EE33000","vmaddr":"7FFF4FEEA000","buildId":"81BF3A8257193B54ABA976C82D932CAC"},{"path":"/usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib","machType":6,"b":"7FFF6EE83000","vmaddr":"7FFF4FF3A000","buildId":"1187BFE8457632478177481554E1F9E7"},{"path":"/usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib","machType":6,"b":"7FFF6F141000","vmaddr":"7FFF501F8000","buildId":"6355EE2D54563CA8A227B96E8F1E2AF8"}]}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-13T11:12:27.657+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31427,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"  Frame: {frame}","attr":{"frame":{"a":"10AE5F52C","b":"108CFB000","o":"216452C","s":"_ZN5mongo18stack_trace_detail12_GLOBAL__N_119printStackTraceImplERKNS1_7OptionsEPNS_14StackTraceSinkE","s+":"10C"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-13T11:12:27.657+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31427,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"  Frame: {frame}","attr":{"frame":{"a":"10AE60C38","b":"108CFB000","o":"2165C38","s":"_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceEv","s+":"28"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-13T11:12:27.657+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31427,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"  Frame: {frame}","attr":{"frame":{"a":"10AE5E76B","b":"108CFB000","o":"216376B","s":"_ZN5mongo12_GLOBAL__N_116abruptQuitActionEiP9__siginfoPv","s+":"BB"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-13T11:12:27.657+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31427,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"  Frame: {frame}","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FFF6F142F5A","b":"7FFF6F141000","o":"1F5A","s":"_sigtramp","s+":"1A"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-13T11:12:27.657+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31427,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"  Frame: {frame}","attr":{"frame":{"a":"0"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-13T11:12:27.657+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31427,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"  Frame: {frame}","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FFF6EEE01AE","b":"7FFF6EE83000","o":"5D1AE","s":"abort","s+":"7F"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-13T11:12:27.657+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31427,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"  Frame: {frame}","attr":{"frame":{"a":"10AE45C67","b":"108CFB000","o":"214AC67","s":"_ZN5mongo25fassertFailedWithLocationEiPKcj","s+":"197"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-13T11:12:27.657+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31427,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"  Frame: {frame}","attr":{"frame":{"a":"108DC82DB","b":"108CFB000","o":"CD2DB","s":"_ZN5mongo12_GLOBAL__N_141mdb_handle_error_with_startup_suppressionEP18__wt_event_handlerP12__wt_sessioniPKc","s+":"1FB"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-13T11:12:27.657+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31427,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"  Frame: {frame}","attr":{"frame":{"a":"108F2D8E7","b":"108CFB000","o":"2328E7","s":"__eventv","s+":"607"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-13T11:12:27.657+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31427,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"  Frame: {frame}","attr":{"frame":{"a":"108F2DB66","b":"108CFB000","o":"232B66","s":"__wt_panic_func","s+":"FD"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-13T11:12:27.657+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31427,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"  Frame: {frame}","attr":{"frame":{"a":"108ED6AFA","b":"108CFB000","o":"1DBAFA","s":"__wt_turtle_read","s+":"2EA"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-13T11:12:27.657+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31427,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"  Frame: {frame}","attr":{"frame":{"a":"108ED66DC","b":"108CFB000","o":"1DB6DC","s":"__wt_turtle_validate_version","s+":"31C"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-13T11:12:27.657+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31427,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"  Frame: {frame}","attr":{"frame":{"a":"108E3B478","b":"108CFB000","o":"140478","s":"wiredtiger_open","s+":"2448"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-13T11:12:27.657+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31427,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"  Frame: {frame}","attr":{"frame":{"a":"108D6F5C7","b":"108CFB000","o":"745C7","s":"_ZN5mongo18WiredTigerKVEngine15_openWiredTigerERKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEENS1_9allocatorIcEEEES9_","s+":"97"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-13T11:12:27.657+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31427,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"  Frame: {frame}","attr":{"frame":{"a":"108D6D19E","b":"108CFB000","o":"7219E","s":"_ZN5mongo18WiredTigerKVEngineC2ERKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEENS1_9allocatorIcEEEES9_PNS_11ClockSourceES9_mmbbbb","s+":"156E"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-13T11:12:27.657+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31427,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"  Frame: {frame}","attr":{"frame":{"a":"108D71B58","b":"108CFB000","o":"76B58","s":"_ZN5mongo18WiredTigerKVEngineC1ERKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEENS1_9allocatorIcEEEES9_PNS_11ClockSourceES9_mmbbbb","s+":"38"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-13T11:12:27.657+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31427,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"  Frame: {frame}","attr":{"frame":{"a":"108D4B5F7","b":"108CFB000","o":"505F7","s":"_ZNK5mongo12_GLOBAL__N_117WiredTigerFactory6createERKNS_19StorageGlobalParamsEPKNS_21StorageEngineLockFileE","s+":"337"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-13T11:12:27.657+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31427,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"  Frame: {frame}","attr":{"frame":{"a":"1097C088A","b":"108CFB000","o":"AC588A","s":"_ZN5mongo23initializeStorageEngineEPNS_14ServiceContextENS_22StorageEngineInitFlagsE","s+":"77A"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-13T11:12:27.657+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31427,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"  Frame: {frame}","attr":{"frame":{"a":"108D071A3","b":"108CFB000","o":"C1A3","s":"_ZN5mongo12_GLOBAL__N_114_initAndListenEPNS_14ServiceContextEi","s+":"463"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-13T11:12:27.657+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31427,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"  Frame: {frame}","attr":{"frame":{"a":"108CFD5FA","b":"108CFB000","o":"25FA","s":"_ZN5mongo12_GLOBAL__N_111mongoDbMainEiPPcS2_","s+":"15DA"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-13T11:12:27.657+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31427,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"  Frame: {frame}","attr":{"frame":{"a":"108CFC019","b":"108CFB000","o":"1019","s":"main","s+":"9"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-13T11:12:27.657+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31427,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"  Frame: {frame}","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FFF6EE34015","b":"7FFF6EE33000","o":"1015","s":"start","s+":"1"}}}
```

This is the previous log:

```
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-12T14:20:34.335+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-12T14:20:34.340+08:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-12T14:20:34.340+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648602, "ctx":"main","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen in use."}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-12T14:20:34.340+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":1169,"port":27017,"dbPath":"/Volumes/A2P7/mongodb","architecture":"64-bit","host":"Users-MacBook-Pro-3.local"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-12T14:20:34.340+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"4.4.2","gitVersion":"15e73dc5738d2278b688f8929aee605fe4279b0e","modules":[],"allocator":"system","environment":{"distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-12T14:20:34.341+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Mac OS X","version":"17.7.0"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-12T14:20:34.341+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{"storage":{"dbPath":"/Volumes/A2P7/mongodb"},"systemLog":{"destination":"file","path":"/Volumes/A2P7/mongodb-log/mongo.log"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-12T14:20:34.343+08:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22271,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Detected unclean shutdown - Lock file is not empty","attr":{"lockFile":"/Volumes/A2P7/mongodb/mongod.lock"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-12T14:20:34.344+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22270,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Storage engine to use detected by data files","attr":{"dbpath":"/Volumes/A2P7/mongodb","storageEngine":"wiredTiger"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-12T14:20:34.344+08:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22302,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Recovering data from the last clean checkpoint."}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-12T14:20:34.344+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22315,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Opening WiredTiger","attr":{"config":"create,cache_size=15872M,session_max=33000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000,close_scan_interval=10,close_handle_minimum=250),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=[recovery_progress,checkpoint_progress,compact_progress],"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-12T14:20:34.765+08:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22435,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger error","attr":{"error":-31809,"message":"[1610432434:765275][1169:0x7fffa74be380], connection: __wt_turtle_read, 387: WiredTiger.turtle: fatal turtle file read error: WT_TRY_SALVAGE: database corruption detected"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-12T14:20:34.765+08:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22435,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger error","attr":{"error":-31804,"message":"[1610432434:765317][1169:0x7fffa74be380], connection: __wt_turtle_read, 387: the process must exit and restart: WT_PANIC: WiredTiger library panic"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-12T14:20:34.765+08:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"-",        "id":23089,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Fatal assertion","attr":{"msgid":50853,"file":"src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_util.cpp","line":520}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-12T14:20:34.765+08:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"-",        "id":23090,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"\n\n***aborting after fassert() failure\n\n"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-12T14:20:34.765+08:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4757800, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Writing fatal message","attr":{"message":"Got signal: 6 (Abort trap: 6).\n"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-12T14:20:34.770+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31431,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"BACKTRACE: {bt}","attr":{"bt":{"backtrace":[{"a":"10955D52C","b":"1073F9000","o":"216452C","s":"_ZN5mongo18stack_trace_detail12_GLOBAL__N_119printStackTraceImplERKNS1_7OptionsEPNS_14StackTraceSinkE","s+":"10C"},{"a":"10955EC38","b":"1073F9000","o":"2165C38","s":"_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceEv","s+":"28"},{"a":"10955C76B","b":"1073F9000","o":"216376B","s":"_ZN5mongo12_GLOBAL__N_116abruptQuitActionEiP9__siginfoPv","s+":"BB"},{"a":"7FFF6F142F5A","b":"7FFF6F141000","o":"1F5A","s":"_sigtramp","s+":"1A"},{"a":"0"},{"a":"7FFF6EEE01AE","b":"7FFF6EE83000","o":"5D1AE","s":"abort","s+":"7F"},{"a":"109543C67","b":"1073F9000","o":"214AC67","s":"_ZN5mongo25fassertFailedWithLocationEiPKcj","s+":"197"},{"a":"1074C62DB","b":"1073F9000","o":"CD2DB","s":"_ZN5mongo12_GLOBAL__N_141mdb_handle_error_with_startup_suppressionEP18__wt_event_handlerP12__wt_sessioniPKc","s+":"1FB"},{"a":"10762B8E7","b":"1073F9000","o":"2328E7","s":"__eventv","s+":"607"},{"a":"10762BB66","b":"1073F9000","o":"232B66","s":"__wt_panic_func","s+":"FD"},{"a":"1075D4AFA","b":"1073F9000","o":"1DBAFA","s":"__wt_turtle_read","s+":"2EA"},{"a":"1075D46DC","b":"1073F9000","o":"1DB6DC","s":"__wt_turtle_validate_version","s+":"31C"},{"a":"107539478","b":"1073F9000","o":"140478","s":"wiredtiger_open","s+":"2448"},{"a":"10746D5C7","b":"1073F9000","o":"745C7","s":"_ZN5mongo18WiredTigerKVEngine15_openWiredTigerERKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEENS1_9allocatorIcEEEES9_","s+":"97"},{"a":"10746B19E","b":"1073F9000","o":"7219E","s":"_ZN5mongo18WiredTigerKVEngineC2ERKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEENS1_9allocatorIcEEEES9_PNS_11ClockSourceES9_mmbbbb","s+":"156E"},{"a":"10746FB58","b":"1073F9000","o":"76B58","s":"_ZN5mongo18WiredTigerKVEngineC1ERKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEENS1_9allocatorIcEEEES9_PNS_11ClockSourceES9_mmbbbb","s+":"38"},{"a":"1074495F7","b":"1073F9000","o":"505F7","s":"_ZNK5mongo12_GLOBAL__N_117WiredTigerFactory6createERKNS_19StorageGlobalParamsEPKNS_21StorageEngineLockFileE","s+":"337"},{"a":"107EBE88A","b":"1073F9000","o":"AC588A","s":"_ZN5mongo23initializeStorageEngineEPNS_14ServiceContextENS_22StorageEngineInitFlagsE","s+":"77A"},{"a":"1074051A3","b":"1073F9000","o":"C1A3","s":"_ZN5mongo12_GLOBAL__N_114_initAndListenEPNS_14ServiceContextEi","s+":"463"},{"a":"1073FB5FA","b":"1073F9000","o":"25FA","s":"_ZN5mongo12_GLOBAL__N_111mongoDbMainEiPPcS2_","s+":"15DA"},{"a":"1073FA019","b":"1073F9000","o":"1019","s":"main","s+":"9"},{"a":"7FFF6EE34015","b":"7FFF6EE33000","o":"1015","s":"start","s+":"1"}],"processInfo":{"mongodbVersion":"4.4.2","gitVersion":"15e73dc5738d2278b688f8929aee605fe4279b0e","compiledModules":[],"uname":{"sysname":"Darwin","release":"17.7.0","version":"Darwin Kernel Version 17.7.0: Fri Jul  6 19:54:51 PDT 2018; root:xnu-4570.71.3~2/RELEASE_X86_64","machine":"x86_64"},"somap":[{"path":"/usr/local/bin/mongod","machType":2,"b":"1073F9000","vmaddr":"100000000","buildId":"6638114D9C633CBCAB6B5A0B73A8739A"},{"path":"/usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib","machType":6,"b":"7FFF6EE33000","vmaddr":"7FFF4FEEA000","buildId":"81BF3A8257193B54ABA976C82D932CAC"},{"path":"/usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib","machType":6,"b":"7FFF6EE83000","vmaddr":"7FFF4FF3A000","buildId":"1187BFE8457632478177481554E1F9E7"},{"path":"/usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib","machType":6,"b":"7FFF6F141000","vmaddr":"7FFF501F8000","buildId":"6355EE2D54563CA8A227B96E8F1E2AF8"}]}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-12T14:20:34.770+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31427,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"  Frame: {frame}","attr":{"frame":{"a":"10955D52C","b":"1073F9000","o":"216452C","s":"_ZN5mongo18stack_trace_detail12_GLOBAL__N_119printStackTraceImplERKNS1_7OptionsEPNS_14StackTraceSinkE","s+":"10C"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-12T14:20:34.770+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31427,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"  Frame: {frame}","attr":{"frame":{"a":"10955EC38","b":"1073F9000","o":"2165C38","s":"_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceEv","s+":"28"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-12T14:20:34.770+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31427,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"  Frame: {frame}","attr":{"frame":{"a":"10955C76B","b":"1073F9000","o":"216376B","s":"_ZN5mongo12_GLOBAL__N_116abruptQuitActionEiP9__siginfoPv","s+":"BB"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-12T14:20:34.770+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31427,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"  Frame: {frame}","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FFF6F142F5A","b":"7FFF6F141000","o":"1F5A","s":"_sigtramp","s+":"1A"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-12T14:20:34.770+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31427,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"  Frame: {frame}","attr":{"frame":{"a":"0"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-12T14:20:34.770+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31427,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"  Frame: {frame}","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FFF6EEE01AE","b":"7FFF6EE83000","o":"5D1AE","s":"abort","s+":"7F"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-12T14:20:34.770+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31427,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"  Frame: {frame}","attr":{"frame":{"a":"109543C67","b":"1073F9000","o":"214AC67","s":"_ZN5mongo25fassertFailedWithLocationEiPKcj","s+":"197"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-12T14:20:34.770+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31427,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"  Frame: {frame}","attr":{"frame":{"a":"1074C62DB","b":"1073F9000","o":"CD2DB","s":"_ZN5mongo12_GLOBAL__N_141mdb_handle_error_with_startup_suppressionEP18__wt_event_handlerP12__wt_sessioniPKc","s+":"1FB"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-12T14:20:34.770+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31427,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"  Frame: {frame}","attr":{"frame":{"a":"10762B8E7","b":"1073F9000","o":"2328E7","s":"__eventv","s+":"607"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-12T14:20:34.770+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31427,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"  Frame: {frame}","attr":{"frame":{"a":"10762BB66","b":"1073F9000","o":"232B66","s":"__wt_panic_func","s+":"FD"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-12T14:20:34.770+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31427,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"  Frame: {frame}","attr":{"frame":{"a":"1075D4AFA","b":"1073F9000","o":"1DBAFA","s":"__wt_turtle_read","s+":"2EA"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-12T14:20:34.770+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31427,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"  Frame: {frame}","attr":{"frame":{"a":"1075D46DC","b":"1073F9000","o":"1DB6DC","s":"__wt_turtle_validate_version","s+":"31C"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-12T14:20:34.770+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31427,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"  Frame: {frame}","attr":{"frame":{"a":"107539478","b":"1073F9000","o":"140478","s":"wiredtiger_open","s+":"2448"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-12T14:20:34.770+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31427,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"  Frame: {frame}","attr":{"frame":{"a":"10746D5C7","b":"1073F9000","o":"745C7","s":"_ZN5mongo18WiredTigerKVEngine15_openWiredTigerERKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEENS1_9allocatorIcEEEES9_","s+":"97"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-12T14:20:34.770+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31427,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"  Frame: {frame}","attr":{"frame":{"a":"10746B19E","b":"1073F9000","o":"7219E","s":"_ZN5mongo18WiredTigerKVEngineC2ERKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEENS1_9allocatorIcEEEES9_PNS_11ClockSourceES9_mmbbbb","s+":"156E"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-12T14:20:34.770+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31427,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"  Frame: {frame}","attr":{"frame":{"a":"10746FB58","b":"1073F9000","o":"76B58","s":"_ZN5mongo18WiredTigerKVEngineC1ERKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEENS1_9allocatorIcEEEES9_PNS_11ClockSourceES9_mmbbbb","s+":"38"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-12T14:20:34.770+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31427,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"  Frame: {frame}","attr":{"frame":{"a":"1074495F7","b":"1073F9000","o":"505F7","s":"_ZNK5mongo12_GLOBAL__N_117WiredTigerFactory6createERKNS_19StorageGlobalParamsEPKNS_21StorageEngineLockFileE","s+":"337"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-12T14:20:34.770+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31427,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"  Frame: {frame}","attr":{"frame":{"a":"107EBE88A","b":"1073F9000","o":"AC588A","s":"_ZN5mongo23initializeStorageEngineEPNS_14ServiceContextENS_22StorageEngineInitFlagsE","s+":"77A"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-12T14:20:34.770+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31427,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"  Frame: {frame}","attr":{"frame":{"a":"1074051A3","b":"1073F9000","o":"C1A3","s":"_ZN5mongo12_GLOBAL__N_114_initAndListenEPNS_14ServiceContextEi","s+":"463"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-12T14:20:34.770+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31427,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"  Frame: {frame}","attr":{"frame":{"a":"1073FB5FA","b":"1073F9000","o":"25FA","s":"_ZN5mongo12_GLOBAL__N_111mongoDbMainEiPPcS2_","s+":"15DA"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-12T14:20:34.770+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31427,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"  Frame: {frame}","attr":{"frame":{"a":"1073FA019","b":"1073F9000","o":"1019","s":"main","s+":"9"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-12T14:20:34.770+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31427,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"  Frame: {frame}","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FFF6EE34015","b":"7FFF6EE33000","o":"1015","s":"start","s+":"1"}}}
```

I am relatively new to mongodb. I have no experience at all with debugging this sort of issue. Really need some help here. The logs are greek to me. I tried searching for this issue on google. There was suggestion to increase ulimit. I tried checking my ulimit:

```
Users-MacBook-Pro-3:S12_RU user$ ulimit
unlimited
```

So does it mean this is not the cause?

I searched on stack overflow, I see this:
[Abort trap: 6 in Mongodb - MAC OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50185943/abort-trap-6-in-mongodb-mac-os)

But no one provided an answer.

I am using macOS 10.13.6. 32GB ram. MacBook Pro 2018.

I never had any issue with using mongo for 2 months until this issue came up.

Please I need some help..

Comment: Your data directory is corrupted. Restore from backup.

Comment: @D.SM are backups done automatically? if not, do u have an article or resource for me to reference how to do auto backups in future, and how to restore from them?

Comment: I got the same error message today. It affects more than one database, so I do not think that the most likely reason is a corrupted data directory. However, it was right after an upgrade to macOS 11.2.3, which may perhaps have something to do with the problem.